# OnLong Click ListView Pop-UP

Tags: java, android, listview, onlongclicklistener

I would like to implement in my listview the longclick, up there I succeeded perfectly :)
Now I would like to create a sort of pop-up with more possibilities, for example, paste, delete, remove, etc ...
To make you understand I found a picture on the internet :) Ve mail below. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: hmm what you ve tried so far..

Comment: i searched in google, popup menu android but i didn't understand so much!

Comment: u need to long click on listview then need to show popup view correct and also that popup items also in listview correct..

Comment: i wrote the code for the long click... but i need to know how to use popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use pop menu like this..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    registerForContextMenu(button);
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}

public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + arg0, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

And xml like this..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:title="edit"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/delete"
    android:title="delete"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    android:title="exit"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the preferred way is to use action mode for these types of menus.  Take a look at this I think this will have all the info you need.  It seems a bit overwhelming, but it's not that bad to implement.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code..

in java

```
 listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    LayoutInflater layoutInflater= (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);             
                    final View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_popup, null);              
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,155,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    ListView listView = (ListView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.list_view);

                    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,menu));


                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(listView, 50, 0);

                    return false;
                }

            });
```

list_popup.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="#44444d"
                 >      
        <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#5c7089"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```